# Why Windows 10 Search forcefully excludes folders from the indexing locations?

Tags: windows-10, windows-search

For some reason, there are a pair of folders I want indexed in the root of my X: drive that can't be fully indexed. I open indexing options, click "Modify" to change locations and checkmark these folders.
After I press OK, both folders appear as indexing locations. A few seconds after that, though, some their subfolders begin to appear in the **excluded** locations column.

For some reason, Windows refuses to index those. My first suspicion was folder persmissions. I have already changed that to be the same for all of them, and even took onwership. The behavior won't change, though.

What might be happening?

EDIT: drive X is a partition in system disk.

Comment: Which folders are these? Is it possible that your computer is infected?

Comment: Also is X: drive    Removable?

Comment: @John No, it's a different partition on the system disk.

Comment: @harrymc Always a possibility, but unlikely, as I'm a careful user and protections are in place. Nothing's been picked up by scan.

Comment: I have never heard of self-adding exclusions. Does this happen when booting in Safe mode? I just wish to add from experience that years ago I had an infection which was only eradicated by the fourth antivirus that I tried, which saved me from total reinstall.

Comment: @harrymc Neither I have ever heard of it. If I haven't seen with my own eyes (que exclusions start to appear one by one in the UI as the folders get scanned), I'd say the user didn't describe it appropriately.

Comment: @harrymc It's actually a full resintall. I had this in a previous install as well. The first thing I thought of was problems with permissions (something quite common as Windows makes a guid for the used id different each install). I took ownership and added the proper permissions to the folder. It didn't fix que issue. The behaviour just repeated exactly in the second install to the very same folders. It's clearly related to some individual folders, then, but I can't spot any obvious differences in flags, permissions, etc.

Comment: Is it possible that these folders are known by Defender? What is inside these folders? Does another antivirus flag anything inside these folders so they need these exclusions (I suggest [Malwarebytes](https://www.malwarebytes.com/))?

Answer (score 1):

Is the X: a network drive? Likely a Group Policy is in effect [prohibiting indexing](https://admx.help/?Category=CopernicDesktopSearch&Policy=Copernic.68c05e16-b741-4f18-a057-420bb4475a34::DontIndexNetworkDrives_Policy).

Network managers would *not* want a shared resource to be indexed by all users.

Comment: No, it's not a network drive. It's a partition within the system disk.